# write callback not executed when using curl within C++

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to basically follow the sample code from http://curl.haxx.se/ to just download webpage, but my WRITEFUNCTION callback is not getting executed at all.  The printf message in function write_callback is not displayed (but it does show the "Ok I guess it worked(?)" message.

It's been a while since I've worked in C so I may be rusty...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_callback (void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);


int main()
{
    printf ("Hello CURL 1.0\n");

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://artifactory.ds.adp.com/artifactory/webapp/home.html");
        curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            printf ("Failed", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Ok I guess it worked?\n");
        }
    }

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}

size_t write_callback (void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    printf ("This is my callback function.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The page (in fact, the server) doesn't appear to exist. Your write callback doesn't get called because there is no data to report.

Comment: And in that case, `curl_easy_perform()` should not be returning `CURLE_OK`.

Comment: The page and the server exist from where I am (i.e. inside my firewall).  I probably should have changed the URL for the question, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, well, changing the URL to example.com actually got the callback function printing (but now it says "Failed").  So it did have something to do with the URL after all.  I'm not sure what though.  Also not sure why its now failing.

Comment: Ok, so changing the return line in the callback to return size*nmemb makes the error go away.  Now just to figure out what it didn't like about the original URL - which is actually the server I need to be able to read data from.

Comment: Looks like it was a proxy issue.  Still weird that the callback didn't get called but it returned CURLE_OK.  But I'm making progress now.  Thanks, all.  I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy server was blocking the connection.